# Заменить в датафрейме все пропущенные значения на средние в этих столбцах

Tags: r

То есть все NA в первом столбце заменяются на среднее значение первого столбца (рассчитанного без учета NA). Все NA второго столбца заменяются на среднее значение второго столбца и т.д.

Как это сделать при помощи функции apply?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) df[is.na(df[,i]),i]<-mean(df[,i],na.rm=T)
```